# How to append char pointer to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, string

```
  char * val = ep->GetValue();
  std::string m="zValue:" + (std::string)val;
```

ep->GetValue() returns a char pointer. I want to append it to a string. I tried as above but it throws the following error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

Comment: I understand that `val == nullptr`... so the error

Comment: Although unrelated to your problem, almost anytime you feel the need to do a C-style cast or conversion (like you do with `(std::string)val`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. If you want to create a string, do it explicitly using `std::string(val)`.

Comment: `ep_>GetValue()` returned null. What do you want the string to look like when `ep->GetValue()` returns null?

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because you try to build a std::string from a `nullptr`. Try:

```
std::string m = "zValue:";
if(char * val = ep->GetValue()) m += val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in reusable form :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string string_from_ptr(const char* p)
{
    std::string retval;
    if (p != nullptr) retval = p;
    return retval;
}


int main()
{
    char* p{ nullptr };
    std::cout << string_from_ptr(p);
    // auto str = string_from_ptr(ep->GetValue());
}
```

Comment: Woops ;) fixed it